# CMDIFrameWnd Caption and CMenu visually merged

Tags: mfc, mdi, cmenu

My application is essentially a CMDIFrameWnd with a CMenu.

Where I can start to create a visual effect that shows, as unique bar, the Caption and the menu? 
What I would like to obtain si something like office 2013 where the caption merge a part of ribbon menu that can be used also to move the application on the desktop.

Comment: Use the ribbon technique... the new VS version support nearly all what is visible in Office 2013... Please make your question more precise.

Comment: I would like to use a cmenu not a ribbon and additionally the effect that I want to achieve is a merge effect between the menu and the caption (as it is also in visual studio 2013 but not in the basic project that you can create with it)